# CakePHP and MVC

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

So I just installed CakePHP and I'm VERY excited to work with it.

However, the MVC model is BLOWING MY MIND.  I looked at the docs and am very impressed, but completely baffled at what to do.

The tutorials and docs show creation of applications that reflect database interaction and etc, but all I want to do right now is create a simple index page.  I've already coded it (html, some style sheets, and basic javascript), but I would like to convert it to fit with the CakePHP model.

Does anyone know of good tutorials to begin the process of translating pages to fit the CakePHP model? Also, I would like to start translating my mindset into the MVC model.

Comment: Good MVC readings: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html, http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/archive/model_view_controller_pattern. This should give you enough information on MVC design pattern.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

Comment: From Nettuts: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/mvc-for-noobs/

Note: After a while you'll notice that CakePHP is a strict MVC framework (which is a good thing!) - Others exist that let you not follow the pattern exactly, but give you the tools to do so if desired. Like CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Here's how to roll your simple index page live without messing around with models, tables, etc:

1. Create a view -> /app/views/pages/index.ctp and plop in your markup, etc.
2. Place your stylesheet in app/webroot/css/whateveryouwanttocallit.css.
3. Pull up app/views/layouts/default.ctp and look for a line in the head that starts with Html->css(...); ?> - change it to `echo $this->Html >css(array('whateveryouwanttocallit'));` - note, no filetype .css on that, just the name. (Also, you can keep the default stylesheet if you want, just add stylesheets to the array to load them in the layout.)
4. Browse to localhost/index and you should see your static page.

Cake rolls with a single default controller already in place - the PagesController. It does not use a model (the `$uses = false;` property.) You can use to that property to disable models if you just want a controller, no database / model functionality. The pages controller and the Cake router are set up to route any request to cake's webroot/:action through the Pages controller without needing to specify /pages/:action. Meaning, localhost/index will route sneakily through pages. (So will localhost/pages/index, but I digress.)

That should get you pointed in the right direction. HTH :)

Comment: Fantastic +1, Bonus points if you can show me the common practice for index pages in CakePHP. Do people usually create a MVC trio for a static index page?

Comment: No, that's what the PagesController is for - static pages. "Index" pages - actual index.php files - have a special use in all MVC frameworks, including Cake. Static index-type pages, such as this one, are just static view files and can be handled with a default generic controller action, in this case the Pages display() action. This is the correct MVC practice for displaying static full pages. You can get much fancier, such as including static navigational elements, dynamic content loading, layouts and themes, but for entire pages, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

This might also aid in understanding [CakePHP MVC models](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/01/06/another-way-to-think-about-mvc/)
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/) MVC tutorial could help you get a better understanding of things.

Answer (score 0):

The link below is going to help you to develop simple CakePHP method:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

After developing a Blog/Post module from above url you can run your application with
`http://[site_url]/posts/index`

By passing the routing principles in `routes.php`

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

As shown in tutorial you can run your index method as base index page of your site or you can say a home page of your site.

I believe this tutorial will help a lot the beginners.